# title.folded not working in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to elastic-search . I have created an index and have used the following analyser

`{
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "number_of_shards": 1,
            "number_of_replicas": 1
        },
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "folding": {
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": ["lowercase", "asciifolding"]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}`

while creating the index . The problem is when i use
`title.folded = "string to be searched"` i am unable to get the results for some data which is present in the index and if i don't use i get the results but then the accent does not work . What could be the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

you only configured that analyzer in the mapping, but you also have to configure this analyzer for certain fields. See [the example](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/analyzer.html) in the analyzer docs.

Comment: i tried this 
`{
 "settings": {
  "index": {
   "number_of_shards": 1,
   "number_of_replicas": 1
  },
  "analysis": {
   "analyzer": {
    "folding": {
     "tokenizer": "standard",
     "filter": ["lowercase", "asciifolding"]
    }
   }
  }
 },
 "mappings": {
  "geo_data": {
   "properties": {
    "text": {
     "type": "text",
     "fields": {
      "name": {
       "type": "text",
       "analyzer": "folding"
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
}` 
but it didn't worked